# android - copying files from asset folder

Tags: java, android

I need to copy all my files from within the assets folder of my app into the SD card so that I can write to this folder via updates from my web service. However, I cannot seem to find the correct path. Below is the code I am currently using which works to copy a database over:

```
public PluginResult execute(String arg0, JSONArray arg1, String arg2) 
{
    String[] resourseFileNames = {"file1.html","file2.html"};   
    final int length = resourseFileNames.length;

    try
    {
        String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
        this.copyOriginal("Databases.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/app_database/");
        this.copyOriginal("0000000000000001.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/app_database/file__0/");
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            this.copyOriginal("file:///android_asset/www/" + resourseFileNames[i],"file:///SDCard/MYAPP/www/" + resourseFileNames[i]);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

void copyOriginal(String file, String folder) throws IOException 
 {
    File CheckDirectory;
    CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
    if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
    { 
    CheckDirectory.mkdir();
    }

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);
    InputStream in = this.ctx.getAssets().open(file);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
    in.close(); 
    out.close();      
}
```

Any help here would be much appreciated, I believe I am close, its the file path I believe is wrong as I keep getting the error (logCat - 'my file path defienet' (No such file or directory).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that my above code was correct, the reason it was not working was due to the file size of my transfer was too big. Simplest solution was to upgrade my firmware to 2.3.3 +

Answer (score 0):

have you this line in your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes I have that, bare in minf the above works when copying the database files, but fails for the rest of the files e.g. the file1.html thanks